# Firebase Firestore not working with Angular 8 basic retrieval

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angular8

Still a noob at Firebase Firestore but it seems this should be a simple remedy.  I am seeing an error when I boot up my Angular 8 app:

```
Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

I have set up my authority to be wide open(I think) as Portal>MyFireStore>Rules Tab>

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      allow read, write;
  }
}
```

I set up an environment.ts variable like so:

```
firebase: {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "place",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "project",
    storageBucket: "storage",
    messagingSenderId: "id",
    appId: "appId"
  }
```

And then hook it up in the app module like so:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule
```

Then I try to test it out with this in my app component

```
constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private parksService: ParksService)  {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.collection('parks').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
  }
```

I know I am doing something simple in a wire up problem.  I am doing the vanilla Angular 8 hosting on port 4200.  From everything I see it should be loading data to a console log.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was from @AJT_82 but he left.  Essentially I tried another database and collection and it worked.  Strange I was following an online tutorial on Pluralsight with another database and it worked exactly with below for rules(this is completely open by the way and not recommended except for testing)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write ;
    }
  }
}
```

I looked at my history and had this but I put in a copy of my exact rules from the other one and the only visible difference was a (space) after the write.  It took within five seconds and started displaying data.

The only other difference I did was in my node package.  I upgraded from firebase@6.2.4 to 6.3.5.  Anyways it's working and it appears to be all Google Cloud Compute side and nothing on my client.